# Composing HTML code (called through Razor) inside Knockout foreach loop

Tags: c#, razor, knockout.js, durandal

my situation is the current one:

```
<fieldset name="sortSearch">
    @Html.CreateSortingControl("views.restricted.widgets.alertdetailwidget.sorting", "searchCriteria.Sorting", "changeSortingDirection", "changeSortingField", GetValueList(SortingValueProvider.ValueProviderId))
</fieldset>
```

In practice I am calling some CS code that will create some a markup with a dropdown and some bindings. For example when a value is selected in this dropdown the function **changeSortingField** will be called. Everything works properly.

What goes wrong is that I want to encapsulate this markup in a Knockout foreach loop that depends on an observable. Sort of this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: FieldSortings, as: 'sortings' }-->
    <fieldset name="sortSearch">
        @Html.CreateSortingControl("views.restricted.widgets.alertdetailwidget.sorting", "searchCriteria.Sorting", "changeSortingDirection", "changeSortingField", GetValueList(SortingValueProvider.ValueProviderId))
    </fieldset>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Which means that when **FieldSortings** increses, the new markup should appear and indeed it does.
Problem is that with this logic none of my functions is anymore called, such as when I select a value from my dropdown the bindings don't work anymore. It feels like that the markup is computed only once (I think). Should I use some kind of particular composition to call the Razor function on the fly? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the markup returned by razor is:

```
 <div class="input-group custom-sort">
<section data-bind="validationElement: searchCriteria.Sorting.Field">
    <label class="select">
        <select data-i18n="[aria-label]accessibility.select.value" class="input-xs select-Sorting-Field" data-bind="value: searchCriteria.Sorting.Field,event: {change: changeSortingField}">
            <option value="" css="searchcriteria-sorting-field-">&lt;Select Order by&gt;</option>
            <option value="DetectionDate" data-default="true" css="searchcriteria-sorting-field-DetectionDate">Detection date</option>
            <option value="Impact" css="searchcriteria-sorting-field-Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Score" css="searchcriteria-sorting-field-Score">Score</option>
        </select>
        <strong class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">
            <i class="fa  txt-color-teal"></i>
            <span data-i18n="views.restricted.widgets.alertdetailwidget.sorting"></span>
        </strong>
    </label>
    <div class="note note-error" style="display: none;" data-bind="validationMessage: searchCriteria.Sorting.Field"></div>
</section>
<label class="input-group-addon" for="sorting-control" data-bind="click: changeSortingDirection">
    <span class="sr-only">Change the sorting direction</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sorting-control" id="sorting-control" data-bind="checked: searchCriteria.Sorting.IsDescending">
    <i></i>
</label>
```

And **FieldSortings** is an Observable array defined as:

```
 self.FieldSortings = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Comment: Razor is server-side. Knockout is client-side. Knockout can't involve the server side without some form of AJAX request (since it is client-side and Razor is server-side). By the time Knockout is involved, Razor is no longer involved.

Comment: @mjwills can't I compose the markup with the bindings once, store it in some template on the client side and then call it with KO when needed?

Comment: @mjwills and indeed the markup generated by Razor is there and repeatable but the bindings don't work inside the foreach loop for some reason

Comment: Can you include the output from the razor call CreateSortingControl please.  that will help us diagnose what the binding issues are.  Also whats the FieldSorting model look like.  Is there any error in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Inside a Knockout foreach loop you need to refer to outsider variables and functions with the **$parent** . Due to this reason it couldn't make the bindings necessaries to work.